# Retrieve the rows in dataframe based on ascending order of a particular column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, updates

i have a dataframe such as,

```
d={'col1' : ['A','A','B','B','C','C','C','D','D'],'col2': [1,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,3]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df


   col1 col2
0   A   1
1   A   3
2   B   2
3   B   3
4   C   1
5   C   2
6   C   3
7   D   3
8   D   3
```

I need to convert the above dataframe values as below,

```
   col1 col2
0   A   1
1   B   2
2   C   1
3   D   3
```

The context is that i need to check col2 value in ascending order and extract the entire row and update in the dataframe such that if once it has retrieved the row , the row should be ignored for the next col2 value.

Comment: Must be a duplicate: `df.sort_values(df.columns).drop_duplicates('col1')`.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('col1')
`

Comment: @QuangHoang Getting error such as "KeyError: Index(['col1', 'col2'], dtype='object')"

Comment: replace `df.columns` by `['col1','col2']`. `sort_values` is just to make sure the smallest is on top. If it's already sorted, use BEN's .

Comment: thank u ..got it!.. i was thinking a complex logic.. python just made it simple :)